# relocatable object file, data section

Tags: c, object-files

i just wrote a simple c program and then generated a relocatable object file to have more understanding on different aspect of object file this is the source code :

```c
 int main(void)
{
 static int a = 1 ;
 int b = 2 ;
 b = a + b ;
 return 0;
}
```

the question is why in the data section contain  assembly instruction :

```
0000000000000000 <a.0>:
   0:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
```

i was expecting  that the data section will contain the address of initialized data
I run gcc on wsl2 ubuntu and this the command : gcc -o file.c file.o

Comment: Was that an optimized build? How did you compile it and on what compiler?

Comment: Why would the data section contain code?

Comment: I remember reading that quality compilers will always try to register variables -- part of the reason why key word "register" is seldom used anymore.   Without seeing all the assembly language, this is my best guess.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the command that produced that output. Most probably you inappropriately let the tool disassemble the data section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're showing that it starts with `01 00`.

```
   0:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
        ^^^^^
```

This is exactly how one would expect it to start. (The next two bytes are going to be `00 00`.) Sure, if you interpret that as code, it would be `add %eax,(%rax)`. But it's not code. It's a 32-bit signed integer.